# How to remove browser scroll bar without removing selectbox scrollbar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS code that removes the scroll bar of my web application, but my problem is it remove the selectbox scroll bar too.

CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the code after a class selector like this:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none;}
.selectbox::-webkit-scrollbar{width:12px;}
```

Keep in mind this will only work in browsers that support webkit.